# Как получить privatekey из keystore на mac osx через java?

Tags: java, macos, mac

Пишу jar для заливки apk в Google Play. Требуется для отправки ключ p12, его поместили в keystore на маке [image: keychain mac osx]

Теперь надо как-то извлечь privatekey.
Начал делать так:

```
String ALIAS = "test1234";
char[] PASSWORD = null;
KeyStore keyStore = KeyStore.getInstance("KeychainStore", "Apple");
keyStore.load(null, null);
PrivateKey privateKey = (PrivateKey)keyStore.getKey(ALIAS, PASSWORD);
```

privateKey получается NullPointerException

Строкой

```
Enumeration<String> al = keyStore.aliases();
```

удается получить список всех сертификатов, а также вытащить public key.
Если не удается получить privatekey - есть ли какие-то готовые решения вытаскивания ключа?
Может оболочки/обертки? 
Может как-то через bash можно вытянуть?

Из того, что удалось накопать в инете, например,
[вот этот вопрос](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6854487/how-do-you-store-a-username-password-in-the-mac-keychain-using-java), но здесь про логин/пароль, я попробовал использовать оболочку osx-keychain-java, но она только для вытаскивания паролей, не для ключей.

P.S. Нам нельзя светить p12 ключ в открытом виде, поэтому запихали в связку ключей. Вот такая вот задача...

Знающие, направьте, плиз, в нужное русло.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Спустя некоторое время нашлось решение:

**1.** Устанавливаем доступ к закрытому ключу в связке ключей. Двойным кликом по ключу откроется окно свойств, где во вкладке "Доступ" ставим "Разрешить всем программам получать доступ к этому объекту"

**2.** На mac'е утилитой [keychain_access](https://github.com/torsten/keychain_access) собираем исполняемый файл.

**3.** В тимсити в command_line вызываем данную утилитку для получения ключа

```
chmod +x keychain_access
PRIVATE_KEY=$(./keychain_access -t private-key "<имя_ключа,_как назван_в_связке_ключей>")
```

**4.** Полученный ключ в String формате передаем в нашу утилитку на Java (что она собой представляет - https://habrahabr.ru/post/281557/)

```
    java -jar public.jar "$PRIVATE_KEY"
```

**5.** Преобразуем String key в PrivateKey с использованием дополнительной библиотеки https://github.com/rtyley/spongycastle
Для себя я отдельно собрал spongycastle-core-1.54.0.0.jar и прицепил к проекту в eclipse.

```
    PrivateKey getPrivateKeyAttempt(String key) {
        String privKeyPEM = key.replace("-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----\n", "")
        .replace("-----END RSA PRIVATE KEY-----", "");

        // Base64 decode the data
        byte[] encodedPrivateKey = Base64.decodeBase64(privKeyPEM);

        try {
            ASN1Sequence primitive = (ASN1Sequence) ASN1Sequence.fromByteArray(encodedPrivateKey);
            Enumeration<?> e = primitive.getObjects();
            BigInteger v = ((ASN1Integer) e.nextElement()).getValue();

            int version = v.intValue();
            if (version != 0 && version != 1) {
                throw new IllegalArgumentException("wrong version for RSA private key");
            }

            BigInteger modulus = ((ASN1Integer) e.nextElement()).getValue();
            BigInteger privateExponent = ((ASN1Integer) e.nextElement()).getValue();

            RSAPrivateKeySpec spec = new RSAPrivateKeySpec(modulus, privateExponent);
            KeyFactory kf = KeyFactory.getInstance("RSA");
            PrivateKey pk = kf.generatePrivate(spec);
            return pk;
        } catch (IOException e2) {
            throw new IllegalStateException();
        } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
            throw new IllegalStateException(e);
        } catch (InvalidKeySpecException e) {
            throw new IllegalStateException(e);
        }
    }
```

**6.** Ну и, собственно, все, пользуемся PrivateKey для заливки.